# Как одно изображение наложить на второе С#

Tags: c#, изображения

Желательно под Win8 RT

Comment: Может тебе еще кнопку на форме показать как делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="image1.png"/>
    <Image Source="image2.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Учтите, что верхняя картинка (image2.png) должна быть с прозрачным фоном, а то она заслонит собой нижнюю.